# Getting information from contract address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, arrays, mapping

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract SubToken{
    using SafeMath for uint;

    struct token{ 
        string  name; 
        string   symbol; 
        uint8  decimals; 
        uint  totalSupply;  
    }

    token public mytokens;

    mapping(address => token) Tokens;
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    constructor(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply)  public{  
        mytokens = token(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply);
        balances[msg.sender]=_totalSupply;  
    }

    function getInformations(address contract_address) public view returns(string memory name,string memory symbol,uint8 decimals,uint totalSupply){
        return (Tokens[contract_address].name,Tokens[contract_address].symbol,Tokens[contract_address].decimals,Tokens[contract_address].totalSupply);
    }

    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining); 
    //function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ; 
    //function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); 
    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); 

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);

}
contract MainContract {
    mapping(address => mapping(address=>uint)) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    address[] public contracts;

    using SafeMath for uint;

    address contract_address;

    struct token{ 
        string  name; 
        string   symbol; 
        uint8  decimals; 
        uint  totalSupply;  
    } 
    mapping(address => token) public tokens;

    function createNewContract(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public returns(address youraddress){ 
        SubToken st = new SubToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply);
        tokens[address(st)] = token(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply);
        return(address(st));
    } 


    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```

Hey guys I am a begginer of solidity so my question about contact address and get some information.

so i have 2 contract first one is sub second one is main. Inside my main contract i have create contract function for create for sub contract and its work well.

but in my sub contract i have get information function. this function take a contract address parameter and return informations. and problem at there
this function doesn’t work .

I check my code but i dont what I suppose to do
Anyone can help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `SubToken` from the `MainContract`, the `SubToken` constructor doesn't add the newly created token to the `SubToken` Tokens mapping and it is this mapping that is used in `getInformations`.

Both your factory (MainContract) and token (SubToken) have mappings for tokens.
I don't know your requirements for having this data captured in both places.  I would have suspected this to only be needed in the MainContract.

A factory creating ERC20 tokens (using the OpenZeppelin ERC20 implementation) could look as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";


contract Token is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {

    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply) 
        public 
        ERC20Detailed(name, symbol, decimals) 
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
}

contract Factory {
    struct tokenData { 
        string name; 
        string symbol; 
        uint8 decimals; 
        uint256 totalSupply;  
    } 

    event TokenCreated(address indexed tokenAddress, string name, string symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply);

    mapping(address => tokenData) private _tokens;

    function createToken(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply) public returns(address tokenAddress){ 
        Token token = new Token(name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply);
        _tokens[address(token)] = tokenData(name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply);

        emit TokenCreated(address(token), name, symbol, decimals, totalSupply);

        return(address(token));
    } 

    function getTokenData(address tokenAddress) public view returns(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply){
        return (_tokens[tokenAddress].name, _tokens[tokenAddress].symbol, _tokens[tokenAddress].decimals, _tokens[tokenAddress].totalSupply);
    }
}
```

If you are creating ERC20 tokens you may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation to see if this meets your needs.
See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: Hello I read your answer and its make sense to me.
"When you create a SubToken from the MainContract, the SubToken constructor doesn't add the newly created token to the SubToken Tokens mapping and it is this mapping that is used in getInformations."
but I am still dont know what should i do can you give me advise like you have to chance this ,add this ,remove this or something like that. Thanks for the comment agaion

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample code which has a factory that creates ERC20 tokens and emits an event when the token is created.